# How to fill table view cell background with colors from an array?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an array like this in `viewDidLoad` which contains `UIColor` that would be used to fill table view cell background colour

```
self.ColorArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                      @"[UIColor redColor];", 
                      @"[UIColor redColor];", 
                      @"[UIColor redColor];", nil]; 

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [self.ColorArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row % self.ColorArray.count]; 
}
```

But this crashes away giving throws this error :

```
-[__NSCFConstantString CGColor]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x137b28 -
```

Comment: Check your code with this modification  self.ColorArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
 [UIColor redColor], 
 [UIColor redColor], 
 [UIColor redColor], nil];

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass color as string.

Try to pass as :

```
  self.ColorArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
     [UIColor redColor], 
     [UIColor redColor], 
     [UIColor redColor], nil]; 


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [self.ColorArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row % self.ColorArray.count]; 

}
```

Comment: #define Color_tblRow1 [UIColor colorWithRed:0.518 green:0.11 blue:0 alpha:1]; /*#841c00*/

Comment: it dont allow me to add color_tblRow1 into array

Comment: Use as : #define RGB(r, g, b)    [UIColor colorWithRed:(r)/255.0 green:(g)/255.0 blue:(b)/255.0 alpha:1]

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing color array with String objects

Instead try adding `UIColor` objects to the array

`self.ColorArray = @[[UIColor whiteColor], @[UIColor redColor], @[UIColor grayColor]];`